# Can USB devices prevent sharing?

Tags: usb

I have Ubuntu 22.04 as a virtual machine and a Raspberry Pi 0W, on the Pi 0W I have a CAN-Bus USB adapter, I have set it up so I can have the Raspberry Pi 0W and CAN-Bus adapter connected to my Tesla using the ODBC-II port.

It works great and I can see the activity on the CAN-Bus in the Ubuntu instance as if the USB was plugged in directly.

I then thought of another application where this would be helpful.  I'm working remotely and the hardware I want to connect to is over 200 miles away.  The normal way to connect to the hardware is using a Lonworks USB adapter.  I've tried to set up this adapter in the same way I did for the CAN-Bus adapter, however it just doesn't work.

Is there something that a vendor can do in their own USB device that prevents it from being shared?

With the USB CAN-Bus adapter I execute in a terminal in Ubuntu:

```
usbip list -r 192.168.5.185
```

The IP above is the Raspberry Pi 0W on my network, this returns a the devices that can be exported, this would return:

```
Exportable USB devices
==================
 - 192.168.5.185
             1-1: OpenMoko, Inc. : Geschwister Schneider CAN adapter (1d50:60f6)
                  : /sys/devices/platform/soc/209800000.usb/usb1/1-1
                  : (Defined at Interface level) (00/00/00)
```

When the Lonworks adapter is present nothing is returned, result is:

```
usbip: error: could not connect 192.168.5.185:3240: System error
```

There is another other posts I've created today over here:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/147150/making-usb-device-stable-and-reliable

https://forum.linux-hardware.org/index.php?topic=150.msg246#msg246

Answer (score 0):

## to answer your question

Not really no. There's no guarantee that the latency of your connection will be low enough to allow the specific device to work, but what you're seeing has nothing to do with failing when communication already works.

## trying to solve the issue at hand

If `usbip list --local` works on your remote machine, then things are generally set up correctly. I suspect it doesn't, and you might need to load the usbip kernel modules correctly. Check for the log output of usbip while you're trying to connect, and if the problem really is the kernel modules, for what `dmesg` has to say after loading the modules.

Comment: The problem is that although the USB device is connected, can0 isn't always showing up when I use ip link, it does it I physically unplug the USB connection then reconnect, so I need a way of doing the same in software.

Comment: Try resetting the USB bus

Comment: Last night I reflashed the SSD card and started over, today its reliable and working fine, so I can only imagine the system develops a fault after updating something?